# Copy the line after the findstr result

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a file with contents like this:

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>8.10</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
```

To extract the line with CFBundleShortVersionString, I can use:

```
(for /f "delims=," %a in ('type "Info.pList" ^|findstr "CFBundleShortVersionString"') do @echo %a) > "CFBundleShortVersionString.txt"
```

gives output

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
```

But how do I extract the line below that please? i.e.

```
<string>8.10</string>
```

I am using the command prompt in Windows 10.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Is this the only `<string>...` line with a number (`x.xx`) in the file?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need those two lines let's just use this trick

You can paste this into the CLI:

```
SET "_Found="
@for /f "delims=," %a in ('
    Type "Info.pList"
  ') do @(
  IF  NOT DEFINED _Found (
    ECHO=%a|find "CFBundleShortVersionString" && (
      SET "_Found=1"
    )
  )  ELSE (
    ECHO=%a
    SET "_Found="
  )
)>> "CFBundleShortVersionString.txt"
```

This will output every match and the first line after each match

Comment: and `ECHO=%a|find "CFBundleShortVersionString" >nul && (` to suppress the output of the matching line(s) and show only the line after it. (and just to note: for use in a batch file, replace each `%a` with `%%a`)

Answer (score 1):

You could first determine the number of the line containing the search string, then read the file and skip that number of lines, like shown in the following [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem // Initialise variables:
set "LineNumber=" & set "LineString="
rem // Let `findstr` precede the matching line(s) with line number plus a colon:
for /F "delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /N "CFBundleShortVersionString" "Info.pList"') do (
    rem // Fetch the line number (remove `if defined LineNumber` if you want the last match):
    if not defined LineNumber set /A "LineNumber=%%L"
)
rem // Check whether the search string has been found:
if defined LineNumber (
    rem // Read the file but skip lines up to the one containing the search string:
    for /F "usebackq skip=%LineNumber% delims=" %%S in ("Info.pList") do (
        rem // This captures the next (non-empty) line following the one containing the search string:
        if not defined LineString set "LineString=%%S"
    )
)
rem // Return result:
echo This is the extracted line: "%LineString%"
endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this answer and also for the comments to explain things - very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to use a regex to get the next line. Select-String is not sed or awk, but it can do some things.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-Content -Path C:\src\t\Get-NextLine.txt -Raw |" ^
        "Select-String -Pattern 'CFBundleShortVersionString.*\n(.*)\n').Matches.Groups[1].Value"') DO (
            SET "NEXT_LINE=%%~A"
    )
ECHO NEXT_LINE is "%NEXT_LINE%"
```

If the goal is to get `8.10` from the line, a little more work on the -Pattern could do that.

NB: If `ECHO %NEXT_LINE%` is used, the redirection characters `<>` will be interpreted. That is why the last output line uses QUOTATION MARK characters.